What is an apologetic to confront Schellenberg's non-resistant divine hiddenness argument?
I was came across an Atheist YouTuber and one of his arguments against the existence of G-d is Schellenberg's non-resistant divine hiddenness argument and its three premises.
How would you address this argument and the premises of this argument from a Christian perspective?
The syllogism is as follows (see SEP entry):

If a perfectly loving God exists, then God would ensure that all capable individuals who are open to a relationship with God are aware of God's existence (non-resistant seekers).

There are some non-resistant individuals who are capable of a relationship with God but do not believe in God's existence.

Therefore, a perfectly loving God does not exist.



"an Atheist YouTuber" is very non-specific. Providing a citation for where "Schellenberg's non-resistant divine hiddenness argument" is defined would help.

All three statements express an opinion.

@NigelJ This is an established philosophical argument of a professional philosopher with many peer review, not mere opinion by an atheist YouTuber.

@RayButterworth Added reference from SEP.

This defense by Gavin Ortlund should help, see also a dialogue.

@GratefulDisciple, thanks. The premises in the SEP document are different from what's presented here (and I think easier to understand). E.g. "There are people who are capable of relating personally to God but who, through no fault of their own, fail to believe.". Two obvious problems with the whole argument are the assumptions: 1) if people have free will, then their choice is "no fault of their own" (clearly false), and 2) time "t" is restricted to the past (false, since people that have rejected God might accept God at some time in the future; e.g. as in my answer).

@GratefulDisciple Yes,indeed. The professional philosopher is expressing an opinion. I agree.

@NigelJ There are opinions constructed on a whim without serious observations and there are serious ones chosen carefully to create a serious argument demanding a serious response by a Christian philosopher who truly understands the difficulty presented at the philosophical sphere instead of strawmanning the opinion in the premise so it's easier to refute. A Christian who has a strong trust in the ability of philosophy (which traditionally has served God to defend the Truth) would not resort to such tactic but would do steelmanning of the opponent's argument first and then refute it.

One of the problems with the argument as presented here is that in order for 3 to follow from 1 and 2, it would be necessary (if not sufficient) for belief and awareness to be the same thing; or more precisely, "X do not believe in God's existence" would have to imply "X are not aware of God's existence." Yet it is not clear that this implication holds; or if awareness is defined strongly enough such that the implication holds, then premise 1 becomes harder to defend.

We've established that questions like this are OK - as long as we're asking for apologetics. I took the liberty of editing the title to reflect what was in the tag.  "What do you say ..." questions invite opinion.  Asking for a known line of reasoning to take on an atheist syllogism can be good stuff - but please flag answers if they read like opinion.

@RayButterworth Yes, the OP doesn't do a good job to make the argument as strong as possible; the SEP entry is 10x better and more authoritative since it's based on responsible reading of Schellenberg's latest book (which made the argument stronger based on feedback to the 1st edition).

The first premise is questionable, the second is false, and the third does not follow even if the first two are presumed.
Note: I'm assuming the first should be understood as "a perfectly loving God would want to make all individuals capable of relationship with him aware of him". Otherwise, premise 1 is actually containing two distinct points (namely that God would desire a relationship with everyone capable and also that God would act in accord with this desire) while premise 3 would add nothing at all. It doesn't affect the overall argument, but I think it's easier to follow if the three premises each make a single point.
I shall explain each point in detail:
1. Questionable: If a perfectly loving God exists, then God would [desire to] ensure that all capable individuals who are open to a relationship with God are aware of God's existence (non-resistant seekers).
This is questionable because the Biblical God on the one hand seems not to be looking for those who are merely "non-resistant", but wants people to actively and strenuously pursue relationship with him (see for example Matt. 11:12, Luke 8:10, Luke 13:22-30). As an analogy, you would certainly not desire for your lover to simply be non-resistant to your love; you want a lover who is actively loving you back.
On the other hand, the Biblical God seeks out relationship with those who are not open to relationship, for example the Apostle Paul's conversion in Acts 9. Think about how a mother will actively love her child even if the child spurns or ignores her love.
Of course, these examples do not prove premise 1 false. I present them merely to show that the perfect love of God is probably more complex than Schellenberg makes out. Even human love is more complex than this. Why should God's love not be even more so?
2. False: There are some non-resistant individuals who are capable of a relationship with God but do not believe in God's existance.
It's easy to judge by appearances, which will lead to thinking that some atheist you might know (or even you yourself) are capable of a relationship with God. While it might seem that way, Christians of all stripes agree that there is no-one unsaved who wanted a relationship with God.
Consider what the Bible has to say about the human condition:

For the mind that is set on the flesh is hostile to God, for it does not submit to God's law; indeed, it cannot. Those who are in the flesh cannot please God. (Romans 8:7-8)


The LORD saw that the wickedness of man was great in the earth, and that every intention of the thoughts of his heart was only evil continually. (Genesis 6:5)


And without faith it is impossible to please him, for whoever would draw near to God must believe that he exists and that he rewards those who seek him. (Hebrews 11:6)

Those human beings who are not in relationship with God are not simply neutral or passive, they "cannot please him" and have hearts whose "every intention" is "only evil continually". See Romans 1:18-25:

For what can be known about God is plain to them, because God has shown it to them. For his invisible attributes, namely, his eternal power and divine nature, have been clearly perceived, ever since the creation of the world, in the things that have been made. So they are without excuse. For although they knew God, they did not honor him as God or give thanks to him, but they became futile in their thinking, and their foolish hearts were darkened. Claiming to be wise, they became fools, and exchanged the glory of the immortal God for images resembling mortal man and birds and animals and creeping things. Therefore God gave them up in the lusts of their hearts to impurity, to the dishonoring of their bodies among themselves, because they exchanged the truth about God for a lie and worshiped and served the creature rather than the Creator, who is blessed forever! Amen.
(Romans 1:19-25)

Thus, we can see that those without a relationship with God are actually not capable of such a relationship.
This seems like a terrible catch 22--and it is--but it is obviously not without solution, as Christians do have a relationship with God. The way this is explained varies among Christian schools of thought, but one thing that we must acknowledge up front is that God does go through great lengths to ensure that people are given the opportunity to be saved. Consider the story of Rahab in Josh.2-6: Given how God was going to destroy the city, there was no reason why sending spies in advance was necessary. Yet, God ensured that the spies would be sent so that Rahab could be saved. In Acts 8, God sent Philip to exactly the right time and place to meet the Ethiopian eunuch and share the Gospel with him. God made use of Paul's shipwreck to save the Maltans (Acts 27). To this day, God continues to send missionaries to obscure corners of the world, and he continues to work through chance meetings to save people. If you spend enough time in Christian community, you will find several people who found faith in extraordinary circumstances. For example, I know a woman who came to faith by reading a Bible she found by accident without ever having met a Christian.
That is why God says "I have been found by those who did not seek me; I have shown myself to those who did not ask for me." (Romans 10:20).
For those in the Molinist school of thought, this is all the explanation necessary--God actually does seek out and initiate a relationship with everyone who is capable of it. God's providence accounts for where people live and who they interact with, so God ensures that anyone who is can have a relationship with him will.
The Calvinist and Lutheran traditions explain it a little differently: In these perspectives, no human being actually has the capacity for relationship with God until God initiates. People are so blinded and corrupted by sin that our will is incapable of desiring (or even, not actively resisting) relationship with God without divine assistance. While people are able to and allowed to enter relationship with God without the help of the Holy Spirit, no-one actually wants this until the Holy Spirit moves them.
The Arminian school of thought teaches that people who are capable of relationship with God actually do build said relationship by their own volition, and they are not held culpable for knowledge that they never learned. Therefore, someone who never heard the gospel might still have a genuine faith in the true God without knowing that they do, basing it on those truths revealed in the natural world and whatever echoes of the truth are found in their own cultural traditions.
In any case, no Christian believes that anyone is headed to hell who did not actually choose to reject relationship with God.
3. Does not follow: Therefore, a perfectly loving God does not exist.
If God has some higher priorities than the dictates of love as interpreted by point 1, then he may conceal himself from some for other reason. (c.f. Romans 9:21-23, which answers a similar question about God's love and wrath with a hypothetical of God's different desires being balanced against one another to create a circumstance which seems nonsensical when one of God's desires is considered in isolation.)

P.S. I am writing this post as a Calvinist; if I have misrepresenting Molinism or Arminianism please let me know.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

As usual in these kind of arguments, it doesn't mention the first premise:

God, love, and every aspect of it, is always completely and only the way I think it must be, and if otherwise I don't understand it so that cannot be true, because I understand everything.

That premise is false, rendering each and every argument that implicitly is based on it, false.

This is one of the best answers I‘ve ever seen on the whole stackexchange network. Very concise and very much to the point.


The first premise implies that Deity is without righteousness.

A genuine relationship cannot exist if there is evil present in one party against the other. The premise implies that Deity would wish to have a relationship, indiscriminately with all humans no matter their individual dispositions in regard to right and wrong, in regard to good and evil, and in regard to what they perceived as the real nature of Deity.
2. The second premise is unproven.
It is just a statement of opinion. Nor does the statement (as stated above) define itself. Experience teaches that humanity on earth, as such, is ill disposed to Deity. Many pretend to religion of various kinds but without genuine knowledge, rather fanciful superstition.
And in any case, how shall humans know anything about Deity ecept Deity reveal what it is and who it is. But then God has done so, in his word. And humanity ignore, or reject or falsiy that word.
The second premise is simply not realistic.
3. Therefore the third premise is incorrect.

Consider 1 Timothy 2:

3 For this is good and acceptable in the sight of God our Saviour;
4 Who will have all men to be saved, and to come unto the knowledge of the truth.
5 For there is one God, and one mediator between God and men, the man Christ Jesus;
6 Who gave himself a ransom for all, to be testified in due time.

Throughout history, billions of people died without ever having a chance to hear God's truth.
Billions of people alive today have heard distorted versions of the truth and have not taken it seriously, or worse, have taken it seriously.
God wants everyone to know him and to be saved, but Salvation will come "in due time".
During this present age, only a very small number of individuals are called.
The Bible calls them "the elect" (people chosen or singled out), because God personally chose them for a specific purpose.
1 Corinthians 15:

51 … we shall all be changed,
52 In a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trump: for the trumpet shall sound, and the dead shall be raised incorruptible, and we shall be changed.
53 For this corruptible must put on incorruption, and this mortal must put on immortality.

When Christ returns, these elect (dead or alive) will receive Salvation, will be instantaneously reborn as immortal spirit beings, siblings of God's firstborn child, Jesus.
Revelation 20:6:

Blessed and holy is he that hath part in the first resurrection: on such the second death hath no power, but they shall be priests of God and of Christ, and shall reign with him a thousand years.

For the next thousand years, they will rule and teach in the Kingdom of God, building a perfect world here on Earth and teaching everyone about God's way.
Revelation 20:5:

But the rest of the dead lived not again until the thousand years were finished.

At the end of the Millennium, there will be a second general resurrection (this time into mortal physical bodies) of everyone that died without being called to salvation.
They too will learn about God's way while living in God's Kingdom, will receive their chance at salvation, and will eventually be judged.
Now consider Mark 3:

28 Verily I say unto you, All sins shall be forgiven unto the sons of men, and blasphemies wherewith soever they shall blaspheme:
29 But he that shall blaspheme against the Holy Ghost hath never forgiveness, but is in danger of eternal damnation:
30 Because they said, He hath an unclean spirit.

There will be a very small number of individuals that will still reject God's spirit.
Living in the Kingdom, they will be well aware of God's existence; this will be their deliberate and conscious decision.
These people are spiritually damaged and will not and cannot be saved.
Instead they will be mercifully destroyed and no longer exist.



Yes: God will "ensure that all capable individuals … are aware of God's existence".




No: At their time of judgement, there will be no individuals that "do not believe in God's existence".




„But the rest of the dead lived not again until the thousand years were finished.“ - They will not live in the millenial kingdom and learn about God‘s ways if they only resurrect after the 1000 years, right?

" a very small number of individuals that will still reject God's spirit"  vs "Because strait is the gate, and narrow is the way, which leadeth unto life, and few there be that find it "

@MikeBorden, I said "During this present age, only a very small number of individuals are called.". The very small number of individuals that will still reject God's spirit" occurs at the end of the Millennium, when everyone that wasn't called during this age will be judged. Revelation 20:11–13 talks about people being judged, not about a kangaroo court automatically condemning everyone.

Doesn't John chapter 3 say that everyone is condemned already?

@MikeBorden, Yes, "The soul that sinneth, it shall die." +"all have sinned, and come short of the glory of God" does condemn everyone.
¶However, "For this is good and acceptable in the sight of God our Saviour; [God] will have all men to be saved, and to come unto the knowledge of the truth.".
¶So those that don't get a chance to learn the truth and be called to salvation during this age (almost everyone that has ever existed) will receive that chance in the Kingdom of God when they are restored to physical life in the second resurrection. Then they will be judged, and a few condemned.

About half of its occurrences can be translated with "all" — albeit often with added nuances such as "all of them" or "the whole of it" or "every one" or "all kinds of".  "All (kinds of) men". From every tribe and tongue and nation.  But we've been here before.  Have a merry Christmas.

Every philosophy begins with (an) assumption(s).  The foundational Christian assumption is that God is true:

He that hath received his testimony hath set to his seal that God is true. - John 3:33

This assumption is based upon reception of God's testimony of Himself in creation, Scripture, and, Christ.  When men contemplate God to the exclusion of what God has revealed about Himself, literally, any imagination is possible.  Without safeguards, philosophy runs amok.
The premises are either ignorant of or dismissive of the biblical narrative regarding man's knowledge and culpability as outlined in Romans chapter 1:  Most especially premise 2 and it's offspring, premise 3.  The Bible is clear that there are no non-resistant non-believers.

Because that which may be known of God is manifest in them; for God hath shewed it unto them. For the invisible things of him from the creation of the world are clearly seen, being understood by the things that are made, even his eternal power and Godhead; so that they are without excuse: 
Because that, when they knew God, they glorified him not as God, neither were thankful; but became vain in their imaginations, and their foolish heart was darkened.

A person may feel as though God is completely hidden and that this constitutes a valid excuse but that is the result of vain imagination and a darkened heart which is the result of not wanting to retain God in their knowledge:

And even as they did not like to retain God in their knowledge, God gave them over to a reprobate mind, to do those things which are not convenient.

When the Scripture says, "The heavens declare the glory of God; and the firmament sheweth his handywork. Day unto day uttereth speech, and night unto night sheweth knowledge. There is no speech nor language, where their voice is not heard.", this is a statement of fact regardless of how it is perceived.  Whatever is, is.
Philosophical arguments such as these always discount the authority of Scripture and invite engagement on their grounds.  The only response is, "It is written...".  It is up to them whether they will kneel before the Word.

I'll take a stab at accepting the premises.  They aren't entirely implausible.
The first seems to make sense.  If a parent greatly loved their child, but the child was adopted at birth, the parent would still want their child to learn about them.
Secondly, there do seem to be well intentioned atheists.  Given the great human evils in the world, especially of the past century, or the gruesomeness of millions of years of animal death, or horrible diseases, or natural disasters, or a large portion of humanity living in extreme suffering, it can be difficult to see how a benevolent divine being is in control.  Furthermore, modern science seems to dispel much need for a divine being as an explanatory mechanism, and also suggests that using a divine being as an explanation has held back humanity's progress for centuries.  It seems possible that people can sincerely hold this kind of view.
So, from that perspective, I can see where the argument is coming from.
The possible responses I can think of:

Something outside of both God's control and the atheist's control has hidden God's existence from the atheist.  This is possible within orthodox Christian theodicy, since libertarian free will is considered outside God's control.  Of their own free will people and Satan have caused great evil, and intentionally hidden God's existence from humanity, so there could be innocent victims of this deception.  All that to say, this is one reason the conclusion does not follow from the premise.

No one is completely free from the knowledge of God, but we must distinguish between kinds of knowledge.  There is explicit knowledge, the sort we can write down on a school test, and there is implicit knowledge that we may not even be consciously aware of.  For the latter case, think Jason Bourne inexplicably knowing the skills of an assassin.  So, in the case of the atheist, all their explicit knowledge of God has been blocked, but there is an implicit knowledge of God that they have and are unaware of.  In this case, too, the conclusion does not follow from the premises.

The knowledge of God is beyond the ability of humans to obtain, and so it must be given to them at some point in their lives, miraculously.  For many people this has not yet occurred, and God has His reasons, so they are still innocently atheist.  Again, the conclusion does not follow in this case.

For some inexplicable reason, a particular human will never come to knowledge of God, through no fault of their own.  Think all babies who die, the mentally impaired, people who lived their entire lives in unconsciousness, someone who has never conceived of the idea of God, and so on.  Such people perhaps cannot be saved, and perhaps can never know God, but God still creates a result for them with a maximal bliss they are capable of enjoying.  All that to say, there may be an entirely natural reason humans never come to know God, because they are incapable of doing so, yet that is still compatible with a loving God who wishes they could know Him.  Similar to how dogs think all humans are also dogs, yet we love them all the same.  So, the conclusion does not follow.


